# Updating a variable inside stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm just playing around with Java 8.
For now I'm trying to understand stream.
So far I haven't seen an example about looping through a map or list then populating a variable that is not part of the map or list.

Here is an example:

```
class RandomObject {
    private int i1;
    private String s1;
    //setter
    //getter
}

// Java 7
RandomObject randomObj = new RandomObject();
Map<Integer, String> mappy = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
Map<Integer, String> collect = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

mappy.put(1, "good map");
mappy.put(2, "nice map");
mappy.put(3, "wow");
mappy.put(4, "mappy the best map");

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mappy.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey() == 2) {
        randomObj.seti1(entry.getKey());
        randomObj.sets1(entry.getValue());
        collect.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

// Java 8
RandomObject randomObj = new RandomObject();
Map<Integer, String> mappy = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

mappy.put(1, "good map");
mappy.put(2, "nice map");
mappy.put(3, "wow");
mappy.put(4, "mappy the best map");

Map<Integer, String> collect = mappy.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey() == 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
// Hmmm i don't know where to put randomObj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a Map, it makes no sense to use such a boilerplate code except for "using streams", because a Map can't have the same key twice.

**This is the best solution**

```
String s = mappy.get(2);
if (s==null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No value with key = 2 were present");
}
new RandomObject(2, s);
```

**But** if you realy whant to use stream, i see three solutions :

The ugly one (even if it is faster) :

```
Map<Integer, String> collect = mappy.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey() == 2)
    .peek(entry -> {
        randomObj.seti1(entry.getKey());
        randomObj.sets1(entry.getValue());
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

`peek()` is used to peek each elements of the stream. And it returns the same stream. (But i would not recommend this way).

A better one (require twice as iteration):

```
Map<Integer, String> collect = mappy.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey() == 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

collect.entrySet().stream()
.forEach(entry -> {
    randomObj.seti1(entry.getKey());
    randomObj.sets1(entry.getValue());
});
```

The better one :

```
Optional<RandomObject> randomObj = mappy.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(map -> map.getKey() == 2)
    .mapToObj(entry -> new RandomObject(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .findFirst();

if (!randomObj.isPresent()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No value with key = 2 were present");
}
```

Comment: Oh nice.. I have some questions though.. Am I using stream incorrectly? Does stream suppose to do this? Should I just stick with Java 7 implementation in this scenario?

Comment: What if I change the setting of object properties to something like a function call.. Is it normal to call it inside the stream?

Comment: It **may** be in some cases, but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. This is personally something that i'll try to avoid, it's not what stream were built for.

Comment: You should place the last solution at the front. In most cases, you can avoid performing two identical lookups (`containsKey(2)`, `get(2)`), via `String s = mappy.get(2); if(s==null) throw new IllegalStateException("No value with key = 2 were present"); RandomObject randomObj = new RandomObject(2, s);` Since we don’t know the purpose of the additional map, it can be created via `Map<Integer, String> mappy = Collections.singletonMap(2, s);` if really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming depends on immutability.

You aren't updating the stream; you're operating on the one you have to create a new one using operations like map, reduce, filter etc.

Comment: Exactly, avoid at all costs mutating stream external stuff. Streams were as well designed to get an "easy" approach to parallelize collection processing, which does basically depend on immutability.

Comment: ohh.. That makes sense. How about .forEach()?

Comment: Same holds true for all stream operations.  That's how functional programming works.